# FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.I get this error

Tags: flutter, gradle

I went through all the threads but couldn't solve the problem. I keep getting this error every time I run the project.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':barcode_scan2:generateDebugProto'.

> protoc: stdout: . stderr: D:\Yeni klasor\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\barcode_scan2-4.2.1\protos: warning: directory does not exist.
> Could not make proto path relative: D:\Yeni klasor\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\barcode_scan2-4.2.1\protos\android_configuration.proto: No such file or directory

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 13s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: Have you followed the Readme instructions for using barcode_scan2 package. If not then read and follow them. This issue will be resolved.